# C# TCP Client and server having trouble

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I was build client and server communication. So I am creating two separate projects. Problem is that this is not working.

Server code:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IPAddress ipaddress = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
    int port = 13000;
    TcpListener server = new TcpListener(ipaddress, port);
    server.Start();
    while (true)
    {
        TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
        label1.Text = "That Connected to Server";
    }
}
```

Client code:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IPAddress ipaddress = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
    int port = 13000;

    TcpClient obj = new TcpClient(ipaddress.ToString(), port);
    while (true)
    {
        label1.Text = "connected";
    }
}
```

This code work fine on console application. But not working on windows form. I am running both application but there is no output on the screen. Please help me how to fix it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Windows application are **event driven**. If you put a `while(true)` loop in your `Form.Load` event then it won't ever exit that function (and you won't ever see any interface). You have to run that code in a separate thread then you'll `BeginInvoke` results to your UI thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows application are **event driven**. If you put a `while(true)` loop in your `Form.Load` event then it won't ever exit that function (and you won't ever see any interface). You have to run that code in a separate thread then you'll `BeginInvoke` results to your UI thread. Something like this:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _thread = new Thread(ListenerThread);
    _thread.IsBackground = true;
    _thread.Start();
}

private Thread _thread;

private void ListenerThread()
{
    IPAddress ipaddress = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
    int port = 13000;
    TcpListener server = new TcpListener(ipaddress, port);
    server.Start();
    while (true)
    {
        TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
        BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(() => label1.Text = "That Connected to Server"));
    }
}
```

Of course on UI callback method you need to perform something more (be careful with with lambdas and anonymous delegates because of captured variables may be not thread-safe). Do the same for client too and you'll be done.